# Change images on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with an x amount of images, when i hover over an image, i want to have it change every second to an image from a list.

This is what i have come up with:
**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nt2t09w/2/)**

```
var images = [];
images[0] = "img1.png";
images[1] = "img2.png";
images[2] = "img3.png";
images[3] = "img4.png";
images[4] = "img5.png";
images[5] = "img6.png";

var i = 0;
setInterval(fadeDivs, 1000);

function fadeDivs() {
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
    $('img').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);
    })
    i++;
}
```

But there are 2 problems with this,

- I want to have all the image links in the html like: `<img src="img1.png"><img src="img2.png">` etc. contained in a div and make it visible or not(think that's the best way).
- And i need it only to happen when i hover over the image.

Do you guys have any ideas? I don't need code, just a push in the right direction :)

To clarify: i have an x amount of images on a page, let's say 25, when i hover over one of the 25 it needs to start changing, i can't have 1 list with images(like the answers) because every image(of the 25) will have a different list.

Comment: Onmouse over hide this element and show next. Do I make sense?

Comment: Yes, but how can i do that with some sort of a timer? because when i keep my mouse on the image it needs to keep changing

Comment: Create a trigger. When mouseover start the function. And do load all images. Not just keep them on array. You will have poor user experience otherwise

Comment: I've updated my answer - it this what your looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, this is what you're looking for. It adds all images to a container and starts an endless rotation when hovering. The interval is stopped, when leaving the element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="active" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&amp;text=X1" alt="">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="active" src="http://placehold.it/200x200&amp;text=Y1" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 250px;
}

.wrapper img {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.wrapper img.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
var images = null;
var running = null;

images = [];
images.push( $('<img/>', { src: 'http://placehold.it/200x200&text=X2', alt: '' } ) );
images.push( $('<img/>', { src: 'http://placehold.it/200x200&text=X3', alt: '' } ) );
wrapper.eq(0).append(images);

images = [];
images.push( $('<img/>', { src: 'http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Y2', alt: '' } ) );
images.push( $('<img/>', { src: 'http://placehold.it/200x200&text=Y3', alt: '' } ) );
wrapper.eq(1).append(images);

wrapper.hover(
    function() {
        var e = $(this);
        running = setInterval(function() {
            var c = e.find('.active');
            var n = c.next();

            if (!n.length) {
                n = e.children().first();
            }

            c.removeClass('active');
            n.addClass('active');    
        }, 1000);
    },
    function() {
        clearInterval(running);
        running = null;
    }
);
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/kfqzhfe9/)

Answer (score 3):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfvys42/)

```
 var images = [];
    images[0] = "img1.png";
    images[1] = "img2.png";
    images[2] = "img3.png";
    images[3] = "img4.png";
    images[4] = "img5.png";
    images[5] = "img6.png";

    var interval;
    var i = 0;

    $(function () {
        $("img").mouseover(function () {
            interval = setInterval(fadeDivs, 1000);
        })
       .mouseout(function () {
                clearInterval(interval);

        });
    });

    function fadeDivs() {
        i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
        $('img').fadeOut(100, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);
        });
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/6sbu79cy/1/

```
<div id="myimage">
<img src="http://www.avsforum.com/photopost/data/2277869/9/9f/9f50538d_test.jpeg" />
</div>



 var images = [];
images[1] = "http://www.avsforum.com/photopost/data/2277869/9/9f/9f50538d_test.jpeg";
images[2] = "http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg";


var i = 0;

$('#myimage').hover(function(){ fadeDivs() });


function fadeDivs() {
    setInterval(function(){
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
    console.log(i)    
    $('img').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(500);
    })


    i++;
         }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){},1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your images with data-index=0 and class identity.

```
//call fadeDivs on mouse over 
$('.yourImages').hover(function(){
  setInterval(fadeDivs(this),100);  
});

//This will create unique fadeOut for all images which have mouse over action
//And separate index loadind
function fadeDivs(image) {   
   $(image).fadeOut(100, function(){
       var index = $(this).data('index');
       index  = index  < images.length ? index : 0;
       $(this).attr('src', images[index]).fadeIn(100);
       $(this).attr('data-index',index)
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution, not much changed to your code.

I've added a hover listener to the image and a variable to the interval so that it can be cleared when you un-hover. Move a thing or two around as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/2nt2t09w/7/

```js
var images = [];
images[0] = "http://placehold.it/100x100";
images[1] = "http://placehold.it/200x200";
images[2] = "http://placehold.it/300x300";
images[3] = "http://placehold.it/400x400";
images[4] = "http://placehold.it/500x500";
images[5] = "http://placehold.it/600x600";

var MyInterval;
var i = 0;
$('img').hover( function() {
    MyInterval = setInterval(fadeDivs, 1000);
    var $this = $(this);
    function fadeDivs() {
        i++;
        i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
        $this.fadeOut(100, function(){
            $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);
        })
    }
}, function() {
    clearInterval(MyInterval);
});
```

```css
img {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i hover over an image, i want to have it change every second to
>   an image from a list.

1. Build the array
2. Pre-load images for flicker-free experience
3. Start a timer on `mouseover`
4. Cycle the array changing the `src`
5. Stop the timer on `mouseout`

> I want to have all the image links in the html like:  etc. contained in a div and make
>   it visible or not(think that's the best way)

That's ok, but it will be better to create the images dynamically based on the size of your array, so that you don't have to hard-code the tags and you can easily dispose them off when required.

Here is a simple example (**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/vz38Lzw7/1/)

**Snippet**:

```js
var x = [
    'http://lorempixel.com/200/200',
    'http://lorempixel.com/201/200',
    'http://lorempixel.com/200/201'
];
var index = 0, $img = $("#image1");

/*--- Pre-load images ---*/
var d = []; // create an array for holding dummy elements
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    d[i] = $("<img>"); // create an img and add to the array
    d[i].attr('src', x[i]).hide(); // add src to img and hide it
    $("body").append(d[i]); // add the img to body to start load
}

/*--- Bind events ---*/
$img.on("mouseover", function () {
    timer = setInterval(changeImages, 1000);
});

$img.on("mouseout", function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
});

/*--- Function to cycle the array ---*/
function changeImages() {
    index = (index + 1) % x.length;
    $img.fadeOut(250, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', x[index]).fadeIn(250);
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image1" src='http://lorempixel.com/200/200' />
```